# Joomla articles from category filled in module positions

Tags: php, joomla

I want to show all the articles from a certain category in different module positions.

How I think it needs to work. I make a plugin that collects all the articles with their information in a central array. This array get emptied one by one in the module positions that I specify. I presume you'll also need a module that adds to the plugin so the plugin needs to know where the items need to go.

But is this the way to go or do you recommend something different? Maybe it already exist in a component or module?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you making your own plugin to show Joomla article since Joomla already have it Just follow the following steps to create article category module in Joomla.

1. Create module under extension->module->new->choose-Article-categories
   [image]
2. Now choose the article category and the position where you want to publish it. You can choose already available positions or you can create it on the fly.

[image]

If you want to publish module in custom position then check this link https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JModuleHelper.html

Comment: This is not what I mean to do. This module displays the articles form a specific category, only I mean to fill up these modules with all the articles, where articles that are already filled in in one module, doesn't get put in another module as well. Let's say I have 100 articles, I need to put these 100 articles in module positions without duplicates. So let's say I have 3 categories modules, I need to distribute the 100 articles over these 3 categories modules without duplicates. I need a plugin/module for that.

Comment: bit confused what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have clients that pay me to put their logo on my website. I need to show all of these logo's one time on my website on different positions on my website.